# Swift: WebThread: EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash UIWebView

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I'm loading a YouTubePlayerView using [this](https://github.com/gilesvangruisen/Swift-YouTube-Player/) library. Sometimes the video loads, sometimes I get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. Here is the dump I'm getting:

[image: ]![]

I'm not sure what is happening. I read in another similar post that I should set `setAnimationsEnabled:NO` but I'm unable to do that. Any other suggestions?

---

Update: Here's the code that's using the player:

```
import YouTubePlayer

class SongViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var videoPlayer: YouTubePlayerView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        videoPlayer.loadVideoID("gCYcHz2k5x0")
        videoPlayer.playerVars = ["playsinline": "1"]

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code that's using the player?

Comment: It's normally correct behavior to declare outlets to subviews as `weak`, but just to rule out any deallocation weirdness here, can you remove the `weak` declaration and see if things improve?

Additionally, is there any message in the console that would contain any clues?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm getting the same error, with same frequency.

Comment: Strange because it will run and subsequently crash without me making any changes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same probleme that I finally fixed running init of `YouTubePlayerView` in the main thread. That's my code :

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { 
    let player = YouTubePlayerView(frame: frame)
    player.loadVideoURL(media.url!)
    self.view.addSubview(player)
})
```